# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, encryption

I am using Eclipse. I need to make a program that encrypts and decrypts and word a user enters, but when I select to encrypt I get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at Encryption.encrypt(Encryption.java:43)
    at Encryption.main(Encryption.java:118)

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Encryption 
{
    public static String message = "";
    public static boolean hasMessage = false;
    public static boolean encrypted = false;
    static char a = 0; 
    static char b;
    static int w;
    static int x;
    static int y;
    static int z;



    public static void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Message: " + message + "\n");
    }

    public static void encrypt(String word)
    {
        if(!hasMessage)
        {
            System.out.println("No message");
            // Tell the user there is no message
        }
        else if(encrypted)
        {
            System.out.println("Message is already encrypted");
            // Tell the user the message is already encrypted
        }

        else
        {
            message = "";
            // Reset the message to blank


            for (message.length();;)
            {
                for (message.charAt(a);; a++) 
                {
                    int w = (int) a * 2;
                    int x = (int) w + 2;  
                    char y = (char) x; 
        }
            }

            //get char from each letter (increase char each time),  cast as int


        }
        System.out.println(message);
        encrypted = true;

        // Using the parameter word, modify message
        // to contain a new value following a predictable pattern
        // Hint:  alter each character's ASCII value by casting
        //        to an integer and using math operators

        // Display the new message
        // Set encrypted to true


    }

    public static void decrypt(String word)
    {
        if(!hasMessage)
        {
            System.out.println("No message");
            // Tell the user there is no message
        }
        else if(!encrypted)
        {
            System.out.println("Message not encrypted");
            // Tell the user the message is not encrypted

        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(message);
            // Like encrypt, but in reverse
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {  
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int menuChoice = 0;

        while(menuChoice != 4)
        {
            System.out.println( "[1] Enter Word\n" + 
                    "[2] Encrypt\n" + 
                    "[3] Decrypt\n" + 
                    "[4] Quit\n");

            menuChoice = sc.nextInt();

            if(menuChoice == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Input message");
                message = sc.next();
                // prompt user to input message
                // assign next word to the class-level variable message
                hasMessage = true;
                encrypted = false;
                // set hasMessage to true
                // set encrypted to false

            }
            else if(menuChoice == 2)
            {
                encrypt(message);
            }
            else if(menuChoice == 3)
            {
                decrypt(message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to start with a very basic tutorial, a very good one is [The Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) by Oracle. I also advise to start with exercises for which the solution is provided.

Comment: I agree with ignis.  You don't yet understand loops.

Answer (score 3):

You don't quite yet understand for loops.  You did not include a condition expression.  `for(initialize; condition; increment)` is the pattern.  You have `for (message.charAt(a);; a++)` which is missing the condition.  A missing condition defaults to true, meaning the loop with continue forever.  So, `a` keeps incrementing until `charAt(a)` bombs.

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
```

As an example, means start with 0, increment i by 1 at the end of loop, stop the loop WHEN i<10 is no longer true.

Comment: Ah thanks for the help ^^ (I just started learning Java a couple months ago)

Answer (score 0):

You're resetting the message to blank then trying to iterate over it

```
        message = "";
        // Reset the message to blank


        for (message.length();;)
        {
```

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the first character of an empty string. Therefore the exception.